Meteor Subscriptions stopping after updating document - only on deployed
I have a meteor react app.
I am having a problem where on the live (production) version, when I update a document, the subscription to the particular document goes away.
When I run it locally, everything works. I update the document, and maintain the subscription.
Here is the code...
This is how I am doing the subscription...
export default withTracker(() => {

  const handles = [
    Meteor.subscribe('singleDesign', Session.get('singleViewDocId')),
  ];

  const loading = handles.some(handle => !handle.ready());

  var doc = Designs.findOne(Session.get('singleViewDocId'));

  return {
    loading,
    doc
  };

})(EditDesign);

This is the code that runs when I submit the form to save the document (client side)...
Meteor.call('designs.update',  Session.get('singleViewDocId'), values, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       message.error("Something went wrong...");
    } else {

       form.resetFields()                                          
       message.success("Design updated");

    }
})

The method that saves the document (server)...
'designs.update'(_id, doc) {
    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorised');
    }

    Designs.update({
        _id: _id
    }, {
         $set: {
           updatedAt: moment().valueOf(),
           ...doc
         }
       },{upsert:true});
    },

The subscription...
Meteor.publish('singleDesign', function (_id) {
   return Designs.find({$or: [{_id: _id, createdBy: this.userId}, {system:{$in: [true]}}]});
});

As mentioned, on local, it works flawlessly. I click to update the document and all the subscriptions (there are other ones as well) stay as they are and do not change.
On the live production version, I click to update the document, and I can see the subscriptions to the document I am saving, stops.
I don't understand why the same code works locally but doesn't on the live version.
I have also tried subscribing to all Designs (rather than just the one I am editing), and again, it works locally, but not on the deployed version. Funny thing is if I see 28 documents in the subscription while editing, then I click to update the document, I then see I only have 27 documents in the subscription. Basically, I lose the subscription to the document I am editing after I save it. Again, this only happens on deployed version.
